# Video js for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html5-video, video.js

how to integrate video.js & VAST, VPAID ADS plugin to wordpress ?
I tried to paste the files in header.php file , but dosent work ?

Please guide  on any plugin that works fine .

Comment: Do you need to display the Videos in your WordPress site by uploading it into the Media Server ah @Swap

Comment: Yes , we need to VAST/ VAPID ads compatibility + scheduling  also , the https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-player/ needs to be customised ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the videos play on the fly in WordPress pages using the shortcodes.

**Videojs HTML5 Player**

Embed video file beautifully in WordPress using Videojs HTML5 Player. Embed HTML5 compatible responsive video in your post/page with video js.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-player/

Comment: Yes , we need to VAST/ VAPID ads compatibility + scheduling  also , the https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-player/ needs to be customised ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

insert below code to your site Head

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js"></script>
```

[you can use of this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-headers-and-footers/)

then, use below example for post new video

```
<video
    id="my-player"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    poster="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
    data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.ogv" type="video/ogg"></source>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
    web browser that
    <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
      supports HTML5 video
    </a>
  </p>
</video>
```